# Android - Trouble parsing enclosure tag in XML

Tags: android, xml

I am using the following code to parse an XML file.  Everything works fine except when I try to read the url attribute from the enclosure tag.  Everything I've read shows to use attributes.getValue("url") but I still seem to get a null value back.  Perhaps I'm not returning it correctly?

The specific line I'm trying to parse is like this:

This is the only info I see in LogCat when I try to play the mp3 using a button.
I/StagefrightPlayer(   33): setDataSource('')
E/MediaPlayer(  275): start called in state 4
E/MediaPlayer(  275): error (-38, 0)
E/MediaPlayer(  275): Error (-38,0)

The lines I believe are causing the problem are at the bottom:
           else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(ENC)) {
               String link = attributes.getValue("url");
               currentMessage.setEnc(link);

Thanks.

```
package com.Demo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import android.util.Log;
import static com.Demo.BaseFeedParser.*;

public class RssHandler extends DefaultHandler{
    private List<Message> messages;
    private Message currentMessage;
    private StringBuilder builder;


    public List<Message> getMessages(){
        return this.messages;
    }
    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        super.characters(ch, start, length);
        builder.append(ch, start, length);
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name)
            throws SAXException {
        super.endElement(uri, localName, name);
        if (this.currentMessage != null){
            if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(TITLE)){
                currentMessage.setTitle(builder.toString());
            } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(LINK)){
                currentMessage.setLink(builder.toString());
            } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(DESCRIPTION)){
                currentMessage.setDescription(builder.toString());
            } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(PUB_DATE)){
                currentMessage.setDate(builder.toString());
            } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(SUMMARY)) {
                currentMessage.setSummary(builder.toString());
            } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(ITEM)){
                messages.add(currentMessage);
            builder.setLength(0);   
        }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
        super.startDocument();
        messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
        builder = new StringBuilder();
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        super.startElement(uri, localName, name, attributes);
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(ITEM)){
            this.currentMessage = new Message();
        }
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(ENC)) {
            String link = attributes.getValue("url");
            currentMessage.setEnc(link);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As we say here hundreds of times each day, post your log cat with the full stack containing the error. Point the line causing the error, and finally see this: http://sscce.org/ We are *not* going to create a new project to debug all that for *you*. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: An example of the xml to parse maybe useful!

Answer (score 2):

This call

```
       String link = attributes.getValue("url");
```

needs the argument to be the XML qualified (prefixed) name, and "url" may just be the local name.

To debug this, you might look at all attributes using `getLength()` to figure out how many there are and then use `getLocalName(int index)` and `getQName(int index)` to show the different forms of the names.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer for XmlPullParser

```
if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("enclosure")) { 
String imgUrl = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "url");
article.setImageUrl(imgUrl);
```